# What is the difference between a Standardization and a Specification?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

While asking this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87238/what-is-standardization-in-computer-science/) on "what exactly is standardization", I remebered that another related term that always came up while reading about C libraries was the term "specification".
To avoid asking more than one question in a single post, I decided to open another post that I hope will clarify what is the difference between this two "popular" terms.
The C POSIX library is defined as a specification of the C standard library, for POSIX systems. Anyway, is Posix usually considered standardized as well, isn't it?
Well, I'm a little bit confused by the use of this words.
I'd love to see reference and examples about other langauges, as much as clarification in the C case.

Comment: C is offtopic here, but methods of specifying programming languages may be ontopic. Let's see where this goes.

Comment: I'm confused.  What exactly is your question?  Please edit the question to state your question clearly. What do you mean by "standardized"? What do you mean by "the C POSIX library"?  There is no such thing. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @D.W. Hi! C Posix Library: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library, it's considered standard respect to GNU C library for example, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697152/what-is-posix-any-other-interface-standards-which-can-replace-it

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the definition of "specification".  Here's one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard).  You asked for the definition of a standard.  Here's one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_standard.